# Lattice Diamond `include not working

Tags: include, verilog, include-path, lattice-diamond

I am using Lattice Diamond and I have a verilog file with a bunch of `define statements to define global constants.

I include this "header" file into another file. It finds the file but there is an error:

"   2049990 ERROR - C:/_libraries/LatticeDiamond/verilog-uart/source/uart/uart_loopback_tb.v(184,38-184,53) (VERI-1128) UART_1_STOP_BIT is not declared
"

I have the directory of the header file set as an include path in the project settings for the implementation as well.

```
/********************************************************************************************
*   @file UART_Header.v
*   @brief
*   Defines UART module parameter constants
*
*   @details
*   This file is to support the UART_core.v 
*
*
*   @namespace UART_
********************************************************************************************/
`ifndef UART_HEADER_FILE
`define UART_HEADER_FILE

// UART core register addresses
`define UART_WRITE_ADDR     = 8'h00;        ///< UART TX address
`define UART_READ_ADDR      = 8'h00;        ///< UART address to read received data
`define UART_LCR_ADDR       = 8'h03;        ///< Line control register
`define UART_LSR_ADDR       = 8'h05;        ///< Line status register
`define UART_DIV_LW_ADDR    = 8'b00000111;  ///< Baud Rate divisor register low word
`define UART_DIV_HW_ADDR    = 8'b00000110;  ///< Baud Rate divisor register high word


// UART core bit masks
`define UART_5_DATA_BITS    = 16'b00000000; ///< 5 data bits mask
`define UART_6_DATA_BITS    = 16'b00000001; ///< 6 data bits mask
`define UART_7_DATA_BITS    = 16'b00000010; ///< 7 data bits mask
`define UART_8_DATA_BITS    = 16'b00000011; ///< 8 data bits mask

`define UART_1_STOP_BIT     = 16'b00000000; ///< 1 stop bit mask
`define UART_1_5_STOP_BIT   = 16'b00000100; ///< 1.5 stop bits mask
`define UART_2_STOP_BIT     = 16'b00001000; ///< 2 stop bits mask

`define UART_PARITY_ENABLE  = 16'b00010000; ///< Enable parity bit mask
`define UART_PARITY_DISABLE = 16'b00000000; ///< Disable parity bit mask


`endif

//EOF
```

Then I have a file that includes that file like so.

```
`ifndef UART_LOOPBACK_TB_FILE
`define UART_LOOPBACK_TB_FILE 

//*******************************************************************************************
//                          Includes
//*******************************************************************************************

`include "source/uart/UART_header.v"

// Rest of the code for this file
.....................
UL_TB_WriteReg((UART_8_DATA_BITS | UART_1_STOP_BIT | UART_PARITY_DISABLE), UART_LCR_ADDR);



...................

`endif
```

Why can't it find my `defines? The file that includes the header file is even in the same directory as the header file itself. Does Lattice Diamond support this?

I also tried `include "UART_header.v" since it's in the same directory, but that gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you mean this:

```
UL_TB_WriteReg((`UART_8_DATA_BITS | `UART_1_STOP_BIT | `UART_PARITY_DISABLE), `UART_LCR_ADDR);
//              ^                   ^                  ^                      ^
```

Things that have been defined in Verilog need to be preceded by a back quote.

Comment: Yes, also my `define statements have "=" and ";" character which is also obviously wrong. I converted them from localparams and did not get rid of those! Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: @user2676271 So they do. I didn't spot that, either.